# R image function in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, colors, plot

I am using the attached image function in R.  I prefer to use this as oppose to heatmap for speed, since I use it for huge matrices (~ 400000 by 400).

The problem in my function is the dynamic range for the color palette, its only blue and yellow in my case.  I have tried several changes to the colorramp line but none gave me the desired output.

The last color ramp option I tried was using a nice package in R called [ColorRamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2D4k.png), which give reasonable results is:

```
library("colorRamps")
ColorRamp = blue2green2red(400)
ColorLevels <- seq(min, max, length=length(ColorRamp))
```

However, is still not as flexible as matlab color ramp options.

I am not very familiar on how to make it look better and with more range, such as in the photo attached.[image]

Please advise me if it'd be possible to change my image function to make look my image like the one in the photo.

The R function I use for plotting images, with raster = TRUE for speed is as follows:

```
# ----- Define a function for plotting a matrix ----- #
myImagePlot <- function(x, filename, ...){
  dev = "pdf"
  #filename = '/home/unix/dfernand/test.pdf'
  if(dev == "pdf") { pdf(filename, version = "1.4") } else{}
     min <- min(x)
     max <- max(x)
     yLabels <- rownames(x)
     xLabels <- colnames(x)
     title <-c()
  # check for additional function arguments
  if( length(list(...)) ){
    Lst <- list(...)
    if( !is.null(Lst$zlim) ){
       min <- Lst$zlim[1]
       max <- Lst$zlim[2]
    }
    if( !is.null(Lst$yLabels) ){
       yLabels <- c(Lst$yLabels)
    }
    if( !is.null(Lst$xLabels) ){
       xLabels <- c(Lst$xLabels)
    }
    if( !is.null(Lst$title) ){
       title <- Lst$title
    }
  }
# check for null values
if( is.null(xLabels) ){
   xLabels <- c(1:ncol(x))
}
if( is.null(yLabels) ){
   yLabels <- c(1:nrow(x))
}

layout(matrix(data=c(1,2), nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(4,1), heights=c(1,1))

 # Red and green range from 0 to 1 while Blue ranges from 1 to 0
 ColorRamp <- rgb( seq(0,1,length=256),  # Red
                   seq(0,1,length=256),  # Green
                   seq(1,0,length=256))  # Blue
 ColorLevels <- seq(min, max, length=length(ColorRamp))

 # Reverse Y axis
 reverse <- nrow(x) : 1
 yLabels <- yLabels[reverse]
 x <- x[reverse,]

 # Data Map
 par(mar = c(3,5,2.5,2))
 image(1:length(xLabels), 1:length(yLabels), t(x), col=ColorRamp, xlab="",
 ylab="", axes=FALSE, zlim=c(min,max), useRaster=TRUE)
 if( !is.null(title) ){
    title(main=title)
 }
# Here we define the axis, left of the plot, clustering trees....
#axis(BELOW<-1, at=1:length(xLabels), labels=xLabels, cex.axis=0.7)
# axis(LEFT <-2, at=1:length(yLabels), labels=yLabels, las= HORIZONTAL<-1,
# cex.axis=0.7)

 # Color Scale (right side of the image plot)
 par(mar = c(3,2.5,2.5,2))
 image(1, ColorLevels,
      matrix(data=ColorLevels, ncol=length(ColorLevels),nrow=1),
      col=ColorRamp,
      xlab="",ylab="",
      xaxt="n", useRaster=TRUE)

 layout(1)
  if( dev == "pdf") {
    dev.off() }
}
# ----- END plot function ----- #
```

Comment: just resample these for plotting efficiently, that is way too much detail for an image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a bias in `colorRampPalette`. I have also adapted the function to define the number of steps between colors in `color.palette`:

```
#This is a wrapper function for colorRampPalette. It allows for the
#definition of the number of intermediate colors between the main colors.
#Using this option one can stretch out colors that should predominate
#the palette spectrum. Additional arguments of colorRampPalette can also
#be added regarding the type and bias of the subsequent interpolation.
color.palette <- function(steps, n.steps.between=NULL, ...){

 if(is.null(n.steps.between)) n.steps.between <- rep(0, (length(steps)-1))
 if(length(n.steps.between) != length(steps)-1) stop("Must have one less n.steps.between value than steps")

 fill.steps <- cumsum(rep(1, length(steps))+c(0,n.steps.between))
 RGB <- matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=fill.steps[length(fill.steps)])
 RGB[,fill.steps] <- col2rgb(steps)

 for(i in which(n.steps.between>0)){
  col.start=RGB[,fill.steps[i]]
  col.end=RGB[,fill.steps[i+1]]
  for(j in seq(3)){
   vals <- seq(col.start[j], col.end[j], length.out=n.steps.between[i]+2)[2:(2+n.steps.between[i]-1)]  
   RGB[j,(fill.steps[i]+1):(fill.steps[i+1]-1)] <- vals
  }
 }

     new.steps <- rgb(RGB[1,], RGB[2,], RGB[3,], maxColorValue = 255)
 pal <- colorRampPalette(new.steps, ...)
 return(pal)
}
```

Here's an example of both (I have squeezed the number of steps between cyan and yellow):

```
Z <- t(as.matrix(1:100))

pal.1 <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "cyan", "yellow", "red"), bias=1)
pal.2 <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "cyan", "yellow", "red"), bias=3)
pal.3 <- color.palette(c("blue", "cyan", "yellow", "red"), n.steps.between=c(10,1,10))

    x11()
par(mfcol=c(1,3))
image(Z, col=pal.1(100))
image(Z, col=pal.2(100))
image(Z, col=pal.3(100))
```

[image]

Also, if your interested, [I wrote a function](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html) that plots a color scale and uses the same arguments as `image`. If you set up your plot layout correctly, this would also be a fast way to plot your matrices and corresponding color scale.

Comment: @Dnaiel - If this does not answer your question, please state why so others may improve on it.