# colorRampPalette function in R

Tags: r, colors

I'm using the colorRampPalette function in R to create a set of colors to use in a scatterplot to color different values.

```
 testcol  <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','red'))
```

Which returns

```
> testcol(6)
[1] "#0000FF" "#3300CC" "#660099" "#990065" "#CC0032" "#FF0000"
```

Then each code is assigned to a value.

In order to improve the visual impact I would like to skip some of the colors so to have a less gradient effect and a more marked change in colors between the values.

Do I need to do some interpolation within the colorRampPalette function?

Comment: Why don't you just return a palette with fewer colours? `colorRampPalette` will return a vector of evenly spaced colours between your start and endpoints. So use `testcol(4)` for instance. Or, use the `RColorBrewer` package and use some nicely predefined colours palettes using the `brewer.pal` function. e.g. `brewer.pal( 4 , "RdBu")`. Check [**their website**](http://colorbrewer2.org/) for more information. They do make pretty colour schemes. Posting some code to make the graphic you have in mind would help more.

Comment: Thanks. Here I found something that I need [menugget](http://menugget.blogspot.ch/2011/11/define-color-steps-for-colorramppalette.html)

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable (even encouraged if no one else has provided you with an answer) to answer your own question, and I would strongly suggest you do this to show what you did.

Comment: Although the other question is less clear than this one, the problem and the solution via menugget.blogspot.com are found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327326/r-image-function-in-r/13329416#13329416.